# Enlarge list of choices of selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have a multiselect `selectInput` in my shiny application. There are 50 possible choices present and default 4 of the 50 choices are shown at once (see screenshot). How can I enlarge this list to, for example, 15 choices?

[image]

**Edit: The code with the answer of Vincent**. (Doesn't work yet)

```
sidebarPanel( 

    uiOutput("dataselect"),
    tags$style(type='text/css', "#view_vars { height: 180px; }"),

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in a css file in the www directory of your app:

```
#view_vars { 
  height: 180px; 
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

where `view_vars` is the name of your selectInput. Increase the height value to show more variables.

Edit: You can also include the following in ui.R but as your app grows putting styling options in a css file is recommended.

tags$style(type='text/css', "#view_vars { height: 180px; }")

Comment: Isn't it possible to adapt something in the ui.R file?

Comment: See my updated answer on how to include style information in ui.R

Comment: I added it after the `uiOutput`command in the ui.r, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: What is the name of the selectInput?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "size" argument of the selectInput function.  I've set it to 15 as you requested in the code below.  Size is compatible with multiselect (`multiple = TRUE`).

```
selectInput(inputId = "YourID", label = "YourLabel", choices = seq(1:50), 
            selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE, width = NULL, size = 15)
```

As discussed in the documentation [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html)